# Is it possible to redefine white-space css property in child elements?

Tags: html, css

I use such html layout to render paragraph and list in one line:

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <p><img src="somesrc" /></p>
    <ul>
       <li>message message message message message.</li>
       <li>message.</li>
       <li>message.</li>
    </ul></div>
```

But white-space: nowrap is applied to text inside li-elements. Is it possible to redefine white-space property in li-elements?

Comment: The code does not render the paragraph and the list in one line. The `white-space` property affects line wrapping but not forced line breaks caused e.g. by `p`, `ul`, and `li` elements. In the given code, and in the absence of other code that might affect the situation, `white-space: nowrap` only prevents line wrapping in the list items, which is not what you want, so why are you using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can set white-space: normal for them.

But I'd suggest you to use css:

```
.block{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.block li{
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Also you can use the simpler note:

```
.block p{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Note that in my example you should add class block to your root div.

Answer (score -3):

```
white-space: normal|nowrap|pre|pre-line|pre-wrap|initial|inherit;
```